# How to Map one Observable<T> to another type Observable<E> in RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, rx-swift

I have one Observable<[String]>, how do I map it to Another Observable < Dash >
where

```
Class Dash{

var list :[String]
var count :int

}
```

for simplicity count is any random integer .

Comment: Have you tried using the `map` function? If so, show your code...

Answer (score 1):

How would you do it if you weren't using Rx? I mean given this:

```
func convert(texts: [String]) -> Dash {
    // what would you put here?
}
```

You do the exact same thing in the Observable map closure that you would do in the above function.